# Is there any function that satisfy these conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm looking for a function that does both the following things:

-rescale a set of values in an interval of my choice (such as normalization, but with a different interval)

-the sum of the new values is the upper bound of the interval I choose

For example, if I have the values $\{1,0.3,0.6\}$ I would like to rescale them to the interval $[0,0.4]$ with the sum of the new values equal to $0.4$

I already know the softmax function, which is used for probabilities and that it can do both things but I would not know how to change the interval or the sum to different values (interval for the softmax is $[0,1]$ and the sum is $1$). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be more specific mathematically? Especially your second point is unclear to me

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: The two conditions can be contradictory. The values $\{1,1,1\}$ cannot be scaled to the interval $[2,3]$ and have a sum of $1$.

Comment: I've just found out that for what I have to do I justhave to use the softmax  function and then multply for a coefficient